# Cannot delete record dynamically due to ORA-01006: bind variable does not exist, How to delete record dynamically?

Tags: sql, dynamic, procedure, delete-row

Okay, continuing on trying to learn dynamic sql, I am now trying to dynamically delete rows based on user input. so here's my code based on what I found online

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON ;

SET TERMOUT ON;
SET ECHO OFF;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE deleteProspect 
    (
    v_cname IN CHAR DEFAULT NULL ,
    v_make IN CHAR DEFAULT NULL ,
    v_model IN CHAR DEFAULT NULL,
    v_cyear IN CHAR DEFAULT NULL,
    v_color IN CHAR DEFAULT NULL,
    v_trim IN CHAR DEFAULT NULL,
    v_ocode IN CHAR DEFAULT NULL
    )
    AS


    l_query VARCHAR2(512) DEFAULT 'DELETE FROM prospect ';




BEGIN



    IF(v_cname IS NOT NULL)
        THEN
        l_query := l_query||'where cname = :v_cname ';
        ELSE
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Customer name cannot be empty ');
    END IF;

    IF(v_make IS NOT NULL)
        THEN
        l_query := l_query||'and make = :v_make ';
        ELSE
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Car make name cannot be empty ');
    END IF;

    IF(v_model IS NOT NULL)
        THEN
        l_query := l_query||'and model = :v_model ';
        ELSE
        l_query :=l_query||'and model IS NULL ';
    END IF;

    IF(v_cyear IS NOT NULL)
        THEN
        l_query := l_query||'and cyear = :v_cyear ';
        ELSE
        l_query :=l_query||'and cyear IS NULL ';
    END IF;

    IF(v_color IS NOT NULL)
        THEN
        l_query := l_query||'and color = :v_color ';
        ELSE
        l_query :=l_query||'and color IS NULL ';
    END IF;

    IF(v_trim IS NOT NULL)
        THEN
        l_query := l_query||'and trim = :v_trim ';
        ELSE
        l_query :=l_query||'and trim IS NULL ';
    END IF;

    IF(v_ocode IS NOT NULL)
        THEN
        l_query := l_query||'and ocode = :v_ocode  ';
        ELSE
        l_query :=l_query||'and ocode IS NULL ';
    END IF;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_query);

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_query 
        USING v_cname,v_make,v_model,v_cyear,v_color,v_trim,v_ocode;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQL%ROWCOUNT||' Rows Deleted');








        EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' No data found in database');

        WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Query returns too many rows of data');

        WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);

END deleteProspect;
/
```

Now I have it so that the user input must at least have cname and make in the delete query,and then this is passed on from another script to this procedure.

However when it runs, whats happening is that it is throwing an error stating that
An error was encountered - -1006 -ERROR- ORA-01006: bind variable does not exist
when I am testing this I found that if in this part of the code

USING v_cname,v_make,v_model,v_cyear,v_color,v_trim,v_ocode;

I change it to

USING v_cname,v_make;

the procedure continues but it does not delete any records in my table.

So my question is what am I doing, wrong and how can I fix so that based on dynamic user input , it deletes that record or records accordingly.

For ex.

In my table I have the record of the following:

```
Talk to me>desc prospect
Name Null? Type
CRAME NOT NULL CHAR(20)
MAKE NOT NULL CHAR(lO)
MODEL CHAR(8)
CYEAR CHAR (4)
COLOR CHAR(l2)
TRIM CHAR(l6)
OCODE CHAR(4) 

Talk to me>select * from prospect where cname='BROCK';
    more...

    CNAME                MAKE       MODEL    CYEA COLOR        TRIM             OCOD
    -------------------- ---------- -------- ---- ------------ ---------------- ----
    BROCK                MERCEDES   M10      2011 BLACK        BLACK            S23
```

But when I run my code this is what happens:

```
    Talk to me>@tdprospect
Enter a customer name: BROCK
Enter a car make: MERCEDES
Enter a model:
Enter a year:
Enter a color:
Enter trim:
Enter an option code:
old  15:        v_cname:= UPPER('&p_cname');
new  15:        v_cname:= UPPER('BROCK');
old  16:        v_make:= UPPER('&p_make');
new  16:        v_make:= UPPER('MERCEDES');
old  17:        v_model:= UPPER('&p_model');
new  17:        v_model:= UPPER('');
old  18:        v_cyear:= UPPER('&p_cyear');
new  18:        v_cyear:= UPPER('');
old  19:        v_color:= UPPER('&p_color');
new  19:        v_color:= UPPER('');
old  20:        v_trim:= UPPER('&p_trim');
new  20:        v_trim:= UPPER('');
old  21:        v_ocode:= UPPER('&p_ocode');
new  21:        v_ocode:= UPPER('');
DELETE FROM prospect where cname = :v_cname and make = :v_make and model IS NULL and cyear IS NULL and color IS NULL and trim IS NULL and
ocode IS NULL
An error was encountered - -1006 -ERROR- ORA-01006: bind variable does not exist

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Thank you,

With Glenn's suggestion I modified it to this:

```
IF(v_cname IS NOT NULL)
        THEN
        l_query := l_query||'where cname = :v_cname ';
        ELSE
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Customer name cannot be empty ');
    END IF;

IF(v_make IS NOT NULL)
    THEN
    l_query := l_query||'and make = :v_make ';
    ELSE
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Car make name cannot be empty ');
END IF;


    l_query := l_query||'and model = NVL(:v_model,model) ';



    l_query := l_query||'and cyear = NVL(:v_cyear,cyear) ';


    l_query := l_query||'and color = NVL(:v_color,color) ';



    l_query := l_query||'and trim = NVL(:v_trim,trim) ';



    l_query := l_query||'and ocode = NVL(:v_ocode, ocode)  ';
```

however it does not seem to work properly completely, since I'm getting the following:

```
Talk to me>@tdprospect
Enter a customer name: chris
Enter a car make: acura
Enter a model:
Enter a year:
Enter a color:
Enter trim:
Enter an option code:
old  15:        v_cname:= UPPER('&p_cname');
new  15:        v_cname:= UPPER('chris');
old  16:        v_make:= UPPER('&p_make');
new  16:        v_make:= UPPER('acura');
old  17:        v_model:= UPPER('&p_model');
new  17:        v_model:= UPPER('');
old  18:        v_cyear:= UPPER('&p_cyear');
new  18:        v_cyear:= UPPER('');
old  19:        v_color:= UPPER('&p_color');
new  19:        v_color:= UPPER('');
old  20:        v_trim:= UPPER('&p_trim');
new  20:        v_trim:= UPPER('');
old  21:        v_ocode:= UPPER('&p_ocode');
new  21:        v_ocode:= UPPER('');
DELETE FROM prospect where cname = NVL(:v_cname,cname) and make = NVL(:v_make,make) and model = NVL(:v_model,model) and cyear =
NVL(:v_cyear,cyear) and color = NVL(:v_color,color) and trim = NVL(:v_trim,trim) and ocode = NVL(:v_ocode, ocode)
0 Rows Deleted

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Talk to me>
Talk to me>
Talk to me>
Talk to me>rollback;

Rollback complete.

Talk to me>@dprospect

Procedure created.

Talk to me>@tdprospect
Enter a customer name: brock
Enter a car make: mercedes
Enter a model:
Enter a year:
Enter a color:
Enter trim:
Enter an option code:
old  15:        v_cname:= UPPER('&p_cname');
new  15:        v_cname:= UPPER('brock');
old  16:        v_make:= UPPER('&p_make');
new  16:        v_make:= UPPER('mercedes');
old  17:        v_model:= UPPER('&p_model');
new  17:        v_model:= UPPER('');
old  18:        v_cyear:= UPPER('&p_cyear');
new  18:        v_cyear:= UPPER('');
old  19:        v_color:= UPPER('&p_color');
new  19:        v_color:= UPPER('');
old  20:        v_trim:= UPPER('&p_trim');
new  20:        v_trim:= UPPER('');
old  21:        v_ocode:= UPPER('&p_ocode');
new  21:        v_ocode:= UPPER('');
DELETE FROM prospect where cname = NVL(:v_cname,cname) and make = NVL(:v_make,make) and model = NVL(:v_model,model) and cyear =
NVL(:v_cyear,cyear) and color = NVL(:v_color,color) and trim = NVL(:v_trim,trim) and ocode = NVL(:v_ocode, ocode)
1 Rows Deleted

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Talk to me>
Talk to me>
Talk to me>
Talk to me>rollback;

Rollback complete.
```

And I know that the chris record exist

```
CNAME                MAKE       MODEL    CYEA COLOR        TRIM             OCOD
-------------------- ---------- -------- ---- ------------ ---------------- ----
CHRIS                ACURA
CHRIS                MERCEDES
```

Also I do not know if this helps but the prospect table has cname,make,model,cyear,color,trim and ocode. My end goal is that depending on the user input , whether if its cname and make only or all seven of the inputs; the records are deleted accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are passing in bind variables that are not used in your dynamic sql. The optional items should still have a bind variable, so replace:

```
IF(v_model IS NOT NULL)
    THEN
    l_query := l_query||'and model = :v_model ';
    ELSE
    l_query :=l_query||'and model IS NULL ';
END IF;
```

with:

```
l_query :=l_query||'and model = NVL(:v_model, model) ';
```

for all the optional blocks so that you always have 7 bind variables in your expression (since that is how many you are passing in).  You may also read up on sql injection.

UPDATE

If you don't care about dynamic sql, you can put something together like this. Some of the NVL stuff can be removed if the prospect table does not allow NULLs in the checked columns.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON ;

SET TERMOUT ON;
SET ECHO OFF;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE deleteProspect(
    v_cname IN CHAR DEFAULT NULL ,
    v_make  IN CHAR DEFAULT NULL ,
    v_model IN CHAR DEFAULT NULL,
    v_cyear IN CHAR DEFAULT NULL,
    v_color IN CHAR DEFAULT NULL,
    v_trim  IN CHAR DEFAULT NULL,
    v_ocode IN CHAR DEFAULT NULL
    )
AS

  K_NULL_MARKER VARCHAR2(32) DEFAULT '~!';

BEGIN

    IF(v_cname IS NULL)
    THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Customer name cannot be empty ');
    END IF;

    IF(v_make IS NULL)
    THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Car make name cannot be empty ');
    END IF;


    DELETE
      FROM prospect
      WHERE cname = v_cname
        AND make  = v_make
        AND NVL(model, K_NULL_MARKER) = NVL(v_model, NVL(model, K_NULL_MARKER))
        AND NVL(cyear, K_NULL_MARKER) = NVL(v_cyear, NVL(cyear, K_NULL_MARKER))
        AND NVL(color, K_NULL_MARKER) = NVL(v_color, NVL(color, K_NULL_MARKER))
        AND NVL(trim,  K_NULL_MARKER) = NVL(v_trim,  NVL(trim,  K_NULL_MARKER))
        AND NVL(ocode, K_NULL_MARKER) = NVL(v_ocode, NVL(ocode, K_NULL_MARKER))
    ;

END deleteProspect;
/
```

Comment: I've tried what you said however, it doesn't work properly always, if I use the brock and mercedes as the search criteria, it works, however if I use any other person such as chris perry and acura, it does not delete any records ...

Comment: Do you recommend any other way to do this delete query dynamically, besides from the way I am currently doing it?

Comment: I tried it, out its working for the majority of the test that I'm trying, sometimes it wont delete but that could be due to an error I did when I was inserting records. Thank you, I was just wondering though, can you explain exactly what your doing with the nvl and k_null_marker? I know approx what the nvl does,but what exactly is happening in your code that you've provided? Also what do you mean, if I dont care about dynamic sql, since when I'm testing it, it seems dynamic since if user input are cname,make, and trim, it deletes accordingly.

Comment: Any time you have a column that is potentially `NULL` or an input that is `NULL` you will have to be very careful with comparisons. Comparisons with `NULL` have unknown results and require operations with special functions.  See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements005.htm. To avoid comparing with a `NULL` value, the code above is assigning a pseudo value (which should never exist in the actual data) in order to allow comparisons. Think of `NVL` as: "if value is null, use this value instead". This query is not dynamic: no `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` was required. Pure DML.